# Prevent DDoS on app authenticating by sms

Tags: node.js, api, security, ddos, server-side-attacks

I have an App where user registers using their phone number and verify using verification code sent in SMS.

From the last 2-3 days I'm getting DDoS attacks from random IPs using random numbers and my SMS balance is getting over quickly.

Backend is in NodeJS

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?